# Apache Jackrabbit Standalone - java.net.MalformedURLException: Nested JAR URLs are not supported

Tags: jackrabbit

I'm currently setting up the Apache Jackrabbit standalone for a future Symfony project. However, I get a malformated url exception in the jackrabbit.log_IS_UNDEFINED file. Apart from the log files, as far as I can tell, no other files are created.

There is a 503 error on port 8080 with the message that the service is unavailable.

I use Java 8 and the error message comes on both Ubuntu and MacOS Catalina, as well as in the Jackrabbit versions 2.16.6 and 2.20.1

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that? Unfortunately, I only have a very basic understanding of this.

```
2020-08-22 09:33:09.879 WARN  [main] Resource.java:191                 Bad Resource: jar:jar:file:/Users/kristiandubek/Development/programs/jackrabbit-standalone-2.16.6.jar!/WEB-INF/lib/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar!/META-INF/resources

2020-08-22 09:33:09.880 WARN  [main] WebAppContext.java:514            Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5700d6b1{/,jar:file:/Users/kristiandubek/Development/programs/jackrabbit-standalone-2.16.6.jar!/,null}{/Users/kristiandubek/Development/programs/jackrabbit-standalone-2.16.6.jar}
java.net.MalformedURLException: Nested JAR URLs are not supported
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:645)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:508)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.newResource(Resource.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.newResource(Resource.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanForResources(MetaInfConfiguration.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanJars(MetaInfConfiguration.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main.run(Main.java:172)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main.main(Main.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Nested JAR URLs are not supported
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:160)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:640)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-4537. You can try the latest stable release (2.20.2).